# Maven - How to place a single resource file on a separate location from the other resource files?

Tags: java, maven

So I created a windows batch file that i would like to include on my build using Maven. I placed it in the `src/main/resources` folder. When I do a `mvn clean install`, my resources end up on a folder named conf in the same directory as the jar file.

Basically I would like to have the windows batch file on the same directory as my jar, with my other resource files in the conf folder.

```
+ conf/
    ... my resource files
- myjar.jar 
- myBatchFile.bat
```

here is a snippet of the maven plugin that does it:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/conf</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.properties</include>
                            <include>**/*.csv</include>

                            <!-- include my batch file -->
                            <include>**/*.bat</include>

                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

AS EXPECTED, my batch file went inside the conf folder.

**Question**: Is there a way to have the batch file sit beside my jar, while all other resource files inside conf?

Comment: hey, i was about to mark it as the answer! providing a seperate `execution` worked like a charm! Please post that again. credits to you. cheers!

Comment: sorry, I wanted to improve it, never mind, undone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your configuration to the following:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/conf</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.properties</include>
                            <include>**/*.csv</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-batch</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <!-- include my batch file -->
                            <include>**/*.bat</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>            
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

We are basically adding a further execution of the same plugin for the same phase which will take care of specific batch file and its copy while removing the batch inclusion from the previous execution.